# PHP move_uploaded_file error

Tags: php, upload

running on **localhost win7 xampp**, this code comes up with error

```
$source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
$upload_dir = "invform/upload/";
 if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
       move_uploaded_file( $source, $upload_dir ) or die ("Couldn't copy");
  }
  else {
        die ('Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.');
  }
```

the error is `Couldn't copy` means that the directory is writable

`$source` is : `D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpFB1.tmp`

what would be the problem?

Comment: Please print the values of $source and check

Comment: I have checked, be `echo $source;` it prints: `D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpFB1.tmp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destination of move_uploaded_file should be a *filename*:

```
$source = $_FILES['fpupload']['tmp_name'];
$upload_dir = "invform/upload/";
$dest = $upload_dir.$source; // gives: invform/upload/phpFB1.tmp
```

Check [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) on the manual.

Comment: yes that's right, it was my mistake copying the code here, I edited the code above.~ seems I have problems with copy either :D

Comment: @safaali I see you 've updated your code after my answer. Does that work now?

Comment: I changed the code to the original mistake in order to let the mess be there ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try this, you missed the file name in the target directory

```
    $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
    $upload_dir = "invform/upload/";
     if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
           move_uploaded_file( $source, $upload_dir.$_FILES['fupload']["name"]  ) or die ("Couldn't copy");
      }
      else {
            die ('Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.');
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the `$_FILES['fupload']['error']` entry against http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
`move_uploaded_file()` can fail for reasons other than an unwritable destination directory (i.e. if the form doesn't have the correct `enctype` attribute, the file will not be uploaded correctly)